# Join data in CQRS patterns from different microservices

Tags: join, microservices, cqrs

I want to apply *CQRS pattern* in a project but i don't understand how can i *join* and *denormalize* data.

Consider a data model where there are 2 entities: *Product* and *Store* in a many to many relationship and an attribute named *stock* (the product quantity in a particular store) as a relationship attribute.

Consider also that I already created 2 microservices:

- *ProductService*: responsible to handle CUD operations on products;
- *StoreService*: responsible to handle CUD operations on stores. The entity *ProductStore* is managed by this service.

At this point, I want to create a third microservice that is responsible to join the data of ProductService and StoreService in order to retrieve all the available products. Here, CQRS pattern seems like the best solution: I will create a materialized view and I will synchronize it using domains events published by the other 2 microservices. Great!

**And now the doubts**.

Suppose the materialized view has the following columns:

*product_sku, product_name, stock, store_name, store_address*.

When I update a *Product* entity or *Store* entity there is no problem to sync the view because I already have data on it. But what about when I receive a *ProductCreated* event? This event has only information about product and nothing else, so stock, store_name, store_address will be NULL. How can I save this event in my view? Should i save incomplete data somewhere else and update my view when I will receive complete data?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**CQRS , Event sourcing and Materialized view**

Your are right, Generally CQRS , materialized view goes with Event sourcing pattern. Which means that we keep on adding our events into event store (this is single point of truth). We generate materialized view by scheduling the job that would read the data from event store and create/update materialized view or we can generate the materialized view following by event trigger. So when you would get store service event (that's probably after product event) then you know that's your last event for particular transaction and query event store to update materialized view and you will have all the data. In short keep dumping in event store and query at once your event store to update your materialized view. Adding event source itself can be complicated so don't over complicated if you can mange without it.

**Your case**

If you are not using event store then in your case you save the partial/incomplete information in the Materialized view and keep updating it when other inflight events arrive.  You will have single reference/key against which you will be updating your data in materialized view. Since the whole system is eventual consistent you will have to manage how would you like to display incomplete (if you have to) data on frontend or you can flag it if you don't want to show (unflag when last event arrives and information is complete).

[Materialized view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/materialized-view)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So you are saying that even if I receive incomplete data I should update (with an insert operation) my view and set a flag (a column in the materialized view) that is used to identify complete/incomplete records, am i right?. So, in this case, when I run a query to get available products (and I want to retrieve only complete data) I need to filter out incomplete records (example: WHERE is_data_complete = TRUE). Is it a common use case?

Comment: you are right.  The common and right approach is using event sourcing and that's  what i used in past. materialized views advise to update the views using published events or by job. there are not detailed practices around it or atleast i didnt find. so in your case it would work without problem i believe.  however  materilzd views are disposable which can always be regenerated . so you should always have a way to generate the views if required.

Comment: Well, in my project i will use event sourcing for doing this. In this case, how can i query my event store after store event in order to obtain product information?

Comment: Let me warn you that this pattern can be complicated and will come with its own challenges. e.g. you need to choose the right event store (Relational or NoSQL). Since events are stored with the version number and to reach the particular state of the system you will have to replay the events. To update your materilized view you will have to replay the events to reach the particular state.  you can find more here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/event-sourcing